# Events not showing on a custom report of opportunities with activities

Tags: reporting, opportunity, fields, activities, custom-report-type

I've created a custom report type. The primary object is 'opportunities'. The secondary object is activities. The report is set to show all opportunities, with or without activities.
I went into the field settings and made sure that all fields are included.

I now go to actually build a report based on this report type. I can see columns for activities that are tasks, but not the event-only fields.

I checked back in the report type setup and there some of the event fields do appear.

Examples of fields I see in the report type but not actually in the report itself is 'Event SubType' or 'start time'. It seems to only pick up tasks and not events.

An hour of Google and Stack overflow searching has identified the problem; the fact that activities is a combination of the events and task objects. This makes using activities a bit erratic and in this case it is causing Tasks to show while events are missing.

What I have not been able to understand is if there is a workaround here that I'm missing.

Can someone help out?